# How to redirect main window to URL from popup?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a pop-up window with a form in it. On submit of the form, I wish to redirect to a particular page, but on the parent window (*not* on the popup).

How can I achieve this using Javascript?

```
After Application of Josh Idea
```

I am calling a javascript function to submit a form, in this javascript, below is the mentioned code

So Can this be executed as i tried with this and its not working as per my need

```
function instant_popup_post()
{
    var cid         = document.getElementById('product').value;
    var session_id  = document.getElementById('sessid').value;
    if(cid==30)
    {
        alert(document.getElementById('instantpop').onsubmit="opener.location.href = 'http://192.168.1.5/cppl11/bannerbuzznew/full_color_banner.php?&id=+cid+'&info_id=5&osCsid='+session_id;");
        document.instantpop.submit();   
    }
    else if(cid==31)
    {
        document.getElementById('instantpop').onsubmit="opener.location.href ='perforated_window_signs.php?&id='+cid+'&info_id=6&osCsid='+session_id;";
        document.instantpop.submit();   
    }
    else if(cid==32)
    {
        document.getElementById('instantpop').onsubmit="opener.location.href ='preprinted_stock_banner.php?&id='+cid+'&info_id=7&osCsid='+session_id;";
        document.instantpop.submit();
    }   
}
```

plss help

Comment: I reolved It Josh Thanks To u again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From within the popup, you can use the [`opener`](https://dev.mozilla.jp/localmdc/developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.opener.html) property to reference the parent window...

```
opener.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

You can also invoke functions on the parent window...

```
opener.functionName();
```

Of course, the good old [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) restrictions apply here

Comment: Could u pls a bit more eloborative regarding window.opener, I canot fully understand the links u provided

Comment: @OM Just try something quick and dirty like `<form onsubmit="opener.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';">`

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use showModalDialog, so you will be freezing the parent window, and after it is done, you can send a variable to parent and do the redirect:

MainWindow:

```
function ShowModalForm()
{
    var urlToRedirect = window.showModalDialog('url');
    if (urlToRedirect) 
       window.location = urlToRedirect;
}
```

Popup Window:

```
function buttonAcceptClicked()
{
    //Do stuff you need
    window.returnValue = "new url";
    window.close()
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a lot of information about this.

Comment: Can U Show me Some Application of this stuff?

Comment: @OM The Eternity, the idea of the Modal popups is to stop the "parent thread" while it is opened, so if you have a form in your modal the parent execution will pause in the line window.showModalDialog until that modal is closed, after that it's gonna continue using the returned var.

Comment: @Josh I agree, that will only work with IE. @OM take that in concideration befor going into it hehe.